# Check if file descriptor opened with O_NONBLOCK is ready

Tags: linux, serial-port, posix, nonblocking, file-descriptor

**Situation:** In POSIX environment, I use a serial port library which is opening a device via `open(...)` with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag set. As the man page for the `open` call states, the `open` itself does not block with this flag.

**Problem:** I need to flush the input buffers of the serial port right after I open the port. Nevertheless, the serial port might not be ready at that time I am performing the flush operation (the file opening has not finished yet).

**Question:** Is there any way to block on a non-blocking file descriptor before it gets ready in POSIX?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you understand what *"serial port might not be ready"* means, i.e. does that really apply to your situation?  Maybe the simple solution is to use blocking I/O by issuing a `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0)` after the **open()** with the O_NONBLOCK flag.  *"the file opening has not finished yet"* -- That's a nonsensical statement; when the syscall returns the port is open.    Is this a hypothethical problem or a real one?  Where's the code that demonstrates this *"problem"*?

Answer (score -1):

You can use one of the following system calls to wait for the file descriptor you got with open gets ready:
select
poll
epoll